# ERROR Configuring mongoDB using Ansible (MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, ansible, devops, mongodb-replica-set

I'm trying to configure a replicaset of mongodb using ansible,

I succeeded to install mongoDB on the primary server and created the replica-set configuration file except when I launch the playbook, I get an error of type: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.142.150.62:28041

Does anyone have an idea please how to solve this?
attached, the playbook and the error on the Jenkins console

Playbook:

```
---
- name: Play1
  hosts: hhe
  #connection: local
  become: true
  #remote_user: ec2-user
  #remote_user: root
  tasks:

     - name: Install gnupg
       package:
         name: gnupg
         state: present

     - name: Import the public key used by the package management system
       shell: wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

     - name: Create a list file for MongoDB
       shell: echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list

     - name: Reload local package database
       command: sudo apt-get update

     - name: Installation of mongodb-org
       package:
         name:  mongodb-org
         state: present
         update_cache: yes

     - name: Start mongodb
       service:
         name: mongod
         state: started
         enabled: yes


- name: Play2
  hosts: hhe
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: create directories on all the EC2 instances
       shell: mkdir -p replicaset/member

- name: Play3
  hosts: secondary1
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: Start mongoDB with the following command on secondary1
       shell: nohup mongod --port 28042 --bind_ip localhost,ec2-18-191-39-71.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com --replSet replica_demo --dbpath replicaset/member &

- name: Play4
  hosts: secondary2
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: Start mongoDB with the following command on secondary2
       shell: nohup mongod --port 28043 --bind_ip localhost,ec2-18-221-31-81.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com --replSet replica_demo --dbpath replicaset/member &

- name: Play5
  hosts: arbiter
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: Start mongoDB with the following command on arbiter
       shell: nohup mongod --port 27018 --bind_ip localhost,ec2-13-58-35-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com --replSet replica_demo --dbpath replicaset/member &

- name: Play6
  hosts: primary
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: Start mongoDB with the following command on primary
       shell: nohup mongod --port 28041 --bind_ip localhost,ec2-3-142-150-62.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com --replSet replica_demo --dbpath replicaset/member &

     - name: Create replicaset initialize file
       copy:
         dest: /tmp/replicaset_conf.js
         mode: "u=rw,g=r,o=rwx"
         content: |
           var cfg =
           {
               "_id" : "replica_demo",
               "version" : 1,
               "members" : [
                   {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "3.142.150.62:28041"
                   },
                   {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "18.191.39.71:28042"
                   },
                   {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "18.221.31.81:28043"
                   }
               ]
           }
           rs.initiate(cfg)

     - name: Pause for a while
       pause: seconds=20

     - name: Initialize the replicaset
       shell: mongo /tmp/replicaset_conf.js
```

The error on Jenkins Consol:

```
PLAY [Play6] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [primary]

TASK [Start mongoDB with the following command on primary] *********************
changed: [primary]

TASK [Create replicaset initialize file] ***************************************
ok: [primary]

TASK [Pause for a while] *******************************************************
Pausing for 20 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [primary]

TASK [Initialize the replicaset] ***********************************************
fatal: [primary]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/mongo 3.142.150.62:28041 /tmp/replicaset_conf.js", "delta": "0:00:00.146406", "end": "2022-08-11 09:46:07.195269", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-08-11 09:46:07.048863", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "MongoDB shell version v5.0.10\nconnecting to: mongodb://3.142.150.62:28041/test?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb\nError: couldn't connect to server 3.142.150.62:28041, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 3.142.150.62:28041 :: caused by :: Connection refused :\nconnect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17\n@(connect):2:6\nexception: connect failed\nexiting with code 1", "stdout_lines": ["MongoDB shell version v5.0.10", "connecting to: mongodb://3.142.150.62:28041/test?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb", "Error: couldn't connect to server 3.142.150.62:28041, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 3.142.150.62:28041 :: caused by :: Connection refused :", "connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17", "@(connect):2:6", "exception: connect failed", "exiting with code 1"]}
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: There are a few issues with your playbook, I can provide solution when playbook is given as text.

Answer (score 0):

You start the service already with

```
service:
  name: mongod
  state: started
  enabled: yes
```

thus `shell: nohup mongod ... &` is pointless. You cannot start the mongod service multiple times, unless you use different port and `dbPath`. You should prefer to start the mongod as service, i.e. `systemctl start mongod` or similar instead of `nohup mongod ... &`. I prefer to use the [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) (typically `/etc/mongod.conf`) rather than command line options.

Plain `mongo` command uses the default port 27017, i.e. it does not connect to the MongoDB instances you started in above task.

You should wait till replica set is initated. You can do it like this:

```
     content: |
       var cfg =
       {
           "_id" : "replica_demo",
           "version" : 1,
           "members" : [
               {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "3.142.150.62:28041"
               },
               {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "18.191.39.71:28042"
               },
               {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "18.221.31.81:28043"
               }
           ]
       }
       rs.initiate(cfg)
       while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) { sleep(1000) }
```

You configured an ARBITER. However, an arbiter node is useful only with an even number of Replica Set members. With 3 members it does not make much sense. Anyway, you don't add the arbiter to your Replica Set, so what is the reason to define it?

Just a note, you don't have to create a temp file, you can execute script directly, e.g. similar to this:

```
shell:
  cmd: mongo --eval '{{ script }}'
  executable: /bin/bash
vars:      
  script: | 
    var cfg =
    {
       "_id" : "replica_demo",
      ...
    }
    rs.initiate(cfg)
    while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) { sleep(1000) }
    print(rs.status().ok)
register: ret
failed_when: ret.stdout_lines | last != "1"
```

Be aware of correct quoting.